# How to add data to firebase subcollection with vuex action?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have some issue accessing data from vuex action argument within the actual action. There is probably a better way to do what I'm trying to do, but for now the only way to get the doc id in which subcollection is, is to pass it inside action argument.

Doing like this, I receive a error message : "*FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined*"

When I check in console for Vue data in component with Vue extension, demand.id is there :

*demandId:"AE5ba0IB1aCwlYDs42ir"*

So maybe I got this error because demandId is type of string? At this point I'm not sure about where to look for answers, maybe someone could direct me through possibles solutions?

**Vue Component :**

```
props: ["demand", "modalId"],


data() {
    return {
      meetingForm: {
        demandId: this.demand.id,
        status: "pending",
        date: "",
        time: "",
        duration: null,
        note: ""
      }
    }
  },

//method:

submitModal(closeCallback) {
      const meeting = {
        demandId: this.meetingForm.demandId,
        status: "Pending",
        date: this.meetingForm.date,
        time: this.meetingForm.time,
        duration: this.meetingForm.duration,
        note: this.meetingForm.duration
      };
      // Dispatch action to create Meeting in DB
      this.$store
        .dispatch("meetings/createMeeting", meeting)
        .then(_ => {
          closeCallback();
          this.$toasted.success("Meeting has been succesfully created!", {
            duration: 3000
          });
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
    }
```

**Vuex action :**

```
createMeeting( meeting) {
      meeting.createdate = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
      const demandId = meeting.demandId
      console.log(demandId)
      return db
        .collection('demands')
        .doc(this.demandId)
        .collection('meetings')
        .add(meeting)
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Vuex API**

actions
type: { [type: string]: Function }

Register actions on the store. The handler function receives a context object that exposes the following properties:

{
state,      // same as `store.state`, or local state if in modules
rootState,  // same as `store.state`, only in modules
commit,     // same as `store.commit`
dispatch,   // same as `store.dispatch`
getters,    // same as `store.getters`, or local getters if in modules
rootGetters // same as `store.getters`, only in modules
}
And also receives a second payload argument if there is one.

**The issue is that I didn't specified context.**

Answer (score 0):

replace this.demandId with demandId

```
createMeeting( meeting) {
      meeting.createdate = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
      const demandId = meeting.demandId
      console.log(demandId)
      return db
        .collection('demands')
        .doc(demandId)
        .collection('meetings')
        .add(meeting)
      },
```

Comment: are you sure that you copy pasted my answer?

Comment: yes, I tried again and same thing. I get "undefined" to console.log(demandId)